# Redo 'Unitarianism' tag description?

Tags: discussion, tags

The first part of the current description for the 'unitarianism' tag is

"a liberal Christian theological movement"

Biblical Unitarians consider themselves unitarians. Is there another, more specific name, for what the tag is currently describing?

Also, can a description be added for Biblical Unitarian?

Comment: You're right it needs fixing, that's not a neutral description. Feel free to submit an edit if you want.

Comment: Made an [edit](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/unitarianism/info). Hope it is better for you. If not, you may propose an edit!

Comment: @KenGraham Big improvement - thank you!